# Is there a way to use Spring boot beans in a Gatling simulation?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, gatling

I am currently writing a Spring boot application that will perform loadtests on another app. I want to use Gatling to manage the tests, but I need it to access the configuration that I defined in beans of my Spring app.

Here is what I would like to see working  :

```java
public class MySimulation extends Simulation {

    @Autowired    
    private JMSConnectionFactoryBeanClass myConnectionFactory;

    public MySimulation() {

        JmsProtocolBuilder jmsProtocol = jms.connectionFactory(myBean);

        ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("My Simulation Scenario")
                .exec(
                        jms("test")
                                .send()
                                .queue("myQueue")
                                .textMessage("message")
                );

        {
            setUp(
                    scn.injectOpen(rampUsers(10).during(5))
            ).protocols(jmsProtocol);
        }
    }
```

When I hardcode the configuration into the simulation class and remove all @Autowired thing, everything works, so it must be comming from the dependency injection. Does anybody know if there is a way to us spring beans in a gatling simulation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Stéphane Landelle advice, here is what I came up with, but instead of creating my app context inside of the simulation, I figured out how to run the simulation along with my spring app using gatling API :

```java
public class GatlingRunner {
    public static void run() {
        GatlingPropertiesBuilder props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder();
        props.simulationClass("path.to.Simulation");
        Gatling.fromMap(props.build());
    }
}
```

This is how I modified my spring app :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        GatlingRunner.run();
    }
}
```

Finally, to use spring beans in the simulation, I wrote a context provider that would make the link between spring and gatling :

```java
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextProvider.context = context;
    }
}
```

Now, to get a bean inside of the simulation, all I needed was this :

```java
Bean myBean = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
                    .getBean("myBean", Bean.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@Autowired`. You have to create an [`ApplicationContext`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-application-context) programmatically and pull the JMSConnectionFactoryBeanClass from it.